# GHCi error: Not in scope 'removeNonUpperCase'

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to compile this function from [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#ready-set-go).

```
 removeNonUppercase st = [ c | c <- st, c `elem` ['A'..'Z']]
```

by placing it into a removeNonUpperCase.hs file.

It compiles fine, but when passing the argument:

```
ghci> removeNonUppercase "Hahaha! Ahahaha!"
```

the compiler says:

```
<interactive>:1:0: Not in scope: 'removeNonUpperCase'
```

Why?

[image: PrintScreen:]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined the method as `removeNonUppercase` (lower case c), but you call it as `removeNonUpperCase` (upper case C).